# how to convert a ndarray to a array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a Question, I have this lines:

```
s=codecs.open('file.csv', encoding="utf-8").read()
array1=np.asarray(s.splitlines())

print(array1)
```

and I become this results from array:

```
['39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K'
 '50, Self-emp-not-inc, 83311, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 13, United-States, <=50K'
 '38, Private, 215646, HS-grad, 9, Divorced, Handlers-cleaners, Not-in-family, White, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K'
 ...
 '36, Private, 146311, 9th, 5, Married-civ-spouse, Machine-op-inspct, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K'
 '47, Self-emp-not-inc, 159869, Doctorate, 16, Married-civ-spouse, Craft-repair, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 50, United-States, <=50K'
 '21, Private, 204641, Some-college, 10, Never-married,']
```

what I want is to transformate it into:

```
[['39', 'State-gov', '77516', 'Bachelors', '13',....,'<=50K]['50'...]]
```

also now is a Array with one row and many columns, and in each column is a string, and I want to change each column into one row with the numbers of columns that have the number of charachters..

I dont have any Idea about it, I wanted splited it but I cant

Could somebody helps me?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1: Generating desired array from file

If you are starting from a csv, you might as well just use [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html):

If `filename.csv` looks like:

```
39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
50, Self-emp-not-inc, 83311, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 13, United-States, <=50K
```

Then:

```
new_arr = np.genfromtxt('filename.csv', dtype='str')

>>> new_arr
array([['39,', 'State-gov,', '77516,', 'Bachelors,', '13,',
        'Never-married,', 'Adm-clerical,', 'Not-in-family,', 'White,',
        'Male,', '2174,', '0,', '40,', 'United-States,', '<=50K'],
       ['50,', 'Self-emp-not-inc,', '83311,', 'Bachelors,', '13,',
        'Married-civ-spouse,', 'Exec-managerial,', 'Husband,', 'White,',
        'Male,', '0,', '0,', '13,', 'United-States,', '<=50K']],
      dtype='<U19')
```

## Method 2: Fixing your array:

Otherwise, if you already have the array:

```
>>> arr
array(['39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K',
       '50, Self-emp-not-inc, 83311, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 13, United-States, <=50K'],
      dtype='<U133')
```

You can iterate through it and split each string to get the output you want:

```
new_arr = np.array([i.split() for i in arr])

>>> new_arr
array([['39,', 'State-gov,', '77516,', 'Bachelors,', '13,',
        'Never-married,', 'Adm-clerical,', 'Not-in-family,', 'White,',
        'Male,', '2174,', '0,', '40,', 'United-States,', '<=50K'],
       ['50,', 'Self-emp-not-inc,', '83311,', 'Bachelors,', '13,',
        'Married-civ-spouse,', 'Exec-managerial,', 'Husband,', 'White,',
        'Male,', '0,', '0,', '13,', 'United-States,', '<=50K']],
      dtype='<U19')
```

Comment: Thanks, the method 1 was my solution!!

Comment: Glad to help :)